# Which filter configuration in kernel rate limit the outgoing packets to 1packet/sec?

Tags: linux, networking, ethernet, limit

Which net filter in kernel configuration other than iptables enable rate limiting on the outgoing packets on ethernet port?

Comment: It depends on what criteria you want to rate limit by. If it's by host or network segment [you can use tc](http://lartc.org/howto/lartc.ratelimit.single.html) if it's by program, you can use `cgroups`.

Comment: Thanks Joel.
I'm working on Android ARM kernel and it has minimal version of tc in which qdisc is not available.
Currently the output packets from the board are sent at the rate of 1 pkt/sec which is very slow (would like to increase this transfer rate).
Disabled several kernel configurations related to net filters and found that its not the case.
Verified using ifconfig that its not from hardware, all the rx packets are processed by CPU. but the tx is sent at the rate of 1pkt/sec